# Combining enums in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums, code-duplication

What would be a good way of combining several enums in TypeScript? My first intuition would tell me to do as follows but this creates code duplication which is prone to errors.

```js
export enum Formats {
  Shirt = 'shirt',
  Fruit = 'fruit',
}

export enum Shirt {
  Yellow = 'yellow',
  Orange = 'orange',
}

export enum Fruit {
  Orange = 'orange',
  Lemon = 'lemon',
}

export enum Item {
    ShirtYellow = 'shirt:yellow',
    ShirtOrange = 'shirt:orange',
    FruitOrange = 'fruit:orange',
    FruitLemon = 'fruit:lemon',
}
```

Use case example. The enums are used to describe four different dialog windows. Shirt dialog handler has defined two dialog windows yellow and orange. The yellow shirt dialog and the orange shirt dialog differ so much that using the same type of dialog for them is not possible. The shirt dialog handler doesn't understand fruit dialogs. The fruit handler is similar but opposite. There is also a global dialog manager responsible for making sure that only one dialog is open at any given time. The global window manager contains a variable representing the open dialog. This variable is stored on the disk to preserve open dialog state over app/page reload.

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Why do you need enum constants for all combinations? Can't you just define a class with one property per enum and if you need to list all combinations, you can simply do that by creating these instances in a loop?

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer combining them like that makes TypeScript believe the combinations are regular strings since there is no type annotation for concatenation of two string literals. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12940

Comment: But where such a string (`'shirt:yellow'`) would be helpful?

Comment: @cyberixae I'm not talking about concatenating strings at all. I'm talking about creating _objects_ with enum properties to represent the combinations, instead of creating combined enums (or strings, or any other primitive type):

class Product {
  format: Format;
  color: Color;
}

Comment: @cyberixae maybe you could tell us what it is that you are actually trying to achieve. I don't think that your proposed solution is the best way, plus TypeScript doesn't offer what you want. Basically, that's a product type, and those are called "classes" in most main stream languages.

Comment: @AlekseyL. I added a use case example. I hope this helps. In the example use case `shirt:yellow` or perhaps `["shirt", "yellow"]` would be the save state stored on disk.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer I added a use case example. Perhaps the use case makes it easier to understand my thinking. Let me know if you think there are still some details missing.

Comment: OK, so introducing another enum here doesn't make sense. If I understand this correctly you're looking to generate combinations of 2 enums?

Comment: @AlekseyL. In my answer below I explore two options of combining the enums. However, I still feel like I'm essentially defining a new enum but since I can't use the enum syntax it requires large amounts of unnecessary boilerplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we should not focus on primitive value types like enums. A proper record or class can do what you want. TypeScript allows you to build ["discriminated unions"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), i.e., a family of types that can be distinguished by one field (the "tag"):

```
export enum ShirtOptions {
  Yellow = 'yellow',
  Orange = 'orange',
}

export enum FruitOptions {
  Orange = 'orange',
  Lemon = 'lemon',
}

interface Shirt {
    kind: 'shirt';
    options: ShirtOptions;
}

interface Fruit {
    kind: 'fruit';
    options: FruitOptions; // Can have a different name
}

type Format = Shirt | Fruit;

function handler(f: Format) {
    switch (f.kind) {
        case "shirt": return doShirtStuff();
        case "fruit": return doFruitStuff();
    }
}
```

And TypeScript does exhaustiveness checking on the switch statement and will tell you, if you don't handle all the cases (See the link for details).

Answer (score 2):

After playing around with this for a bit I came up with the following. There is still duplication but at least there is some cross checking that might help guard against errors. The main problem with this is that it is quite verbose and it is easy to forget one combination.

```js
type Pair<A, B> = [A, B]
const pair = <A, B>(a: A, b: B): Pair<A, B> => [a, b]

type ShirtYellow = Pair<Formats.Shirt, Shirt.Yellow>
type ShirtOrange = Pair<Formats.Shirt, Shirt.Orange>
type FruitOrange = Pair<Formats.Fruit, Fruit.Orange>
type FruitLemon = Pair<Formats.Fruit, Fruit.Lemon>

const ShirtYellow: ShirtYellow = pair(Formats.Shirt, Shirt.Yellow)
const ShirtOrange: ShirtOrange = pair(Formats.Shirt, Shirt.Orange)
const FruitOrange: FruitOrange = pair(Formats.Fruit, Fruit.Orange)
const FruitLemon: FruitLemon = pair(Formats.Fruit, Fruit.Lemon)

export type Item = ShirtYellow | ShirtOrange | FruitOrange | FruitLemon 
export const Item = { ShirtYellow, ShirtOrange, FruitOrange, FruitLemon };
```

Here is my second attempts. This time an object based solution.

```js
type AbstractItem<I extends { kind: Formats, type: any }> = I

export type ShirtItem = AbstractItem<{kind: Formats.Shirt, type: Shirt}>
export type FruitItem = AbstractItem<{kind: Formats.Fruit, type: Fruit}>

export type Item = AbstractItem<ShirtItem | FruitItem>

export const isShirt = (i: Item): i is ShirtItem => i.kind === Formats.Shirt
export const isFruit = (i: Item): i is FruitItem => i.kind === Formats.Fruit

export const getShirt = (i: Item): Shirt|null => isShirt(i) ? i.type : null
export const getFruit = (i: Item): Fruit|null => isFruit(i) ? i.type : null
```